# JSOUP assigning image to view or text to field

Tags: java, android, oracle

I am new to Java and have been assigned a task to implement an image into an imageview via JSOUP.

I am able to parse the image url and such but the problem is whenever I run the app (after assigning the BITMAP) it crashes.

```
 ArrayList<String> name= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> url= new ArrayList<String>();
    int chosenOne = 0;
    ImageView mainImg;

 public class getImageFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL((urls[0]));
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
                return image;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }

 getImageFile getImage = new getImageFile();
        Bitmap image1= null;
        try {
            image1 = getImage.execute(image.get(chosenOne)).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainImg.setImageBitmap(image1);
```

I have been getting the crash all the time now, what could the issue be here?

**LOG CAT ERROR:**

```
                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.fun, PID: 2363
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aakarshm.fun.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                      at com.example.fun.artistguessgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:159)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.818ms
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: @F.Klein, Ive posted it

Comment: Can you copy/mark the out of bounds exception throwing line (159). Looks like you are trying to a value from an empty ArrayList. Try running it in debug mode with a breakpoint an inspect the ArrayList.

Comment: post your MainActivity , the actual bug is there